# Stopping jQuery UI accordion from styling content text/form items

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Hi I want to disable the jQuery accordion from changing the fonts for the content text and form items...

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/APZ6V/

I don't want to set the content to new fonts/sizes I just want to disable the accordion from changing it.

```
$(function() {
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content"
}).show();
```

BTW here are my jquery UI links:

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that jQuery UI tries very hard to give consistent fonts.

You can simply not load the CSS file, and then you'll get your browsers default fonts, but it won't look pretty as you lose all the images/backgrounds/borders/etc. You can try that on the jsfiddle simply by removing the css file from the external resources section of the left menu column.

Realistically, your options are to create your own theme with the font settings you want (see the themeroller utility), or else edit or override the specific css entries you don't like.